# How to get the app store link programmatically in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am using social media sharing in my windows phone 8 app.

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask()
            {
                Title = "My New App",
                LinkUri = new Uri("http://msdn.microsoft.com", UriKind.Absolute),
                Message = "My New App Windows Phone App."
            };

            shareLinkTask.Show();
```

In the URI instead of msdn.microsoft.com(in my eg: above) i want to get my app's store link.I will get the link only after publishing the app.Then how can i programmatically get the link?

Comment: The only "programmatic" way to do it is to copy the ID (GUID) from your app dashboard then generate a URL from that ID in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't seem to get a link (without putting your appid in your app in some way), but the `MarketPlaceDetailTask` is documented as able to go to the current applications page when `ContentIdentifier` is null:

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = 
        new MarketplaceDetailTask
        {
            ContentIdentifier = null,
            ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications
        };

marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

Mind you, I can't get this to work in my debug build...